# Order boxplot at higher level (R, ggplot2)

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, boxplot

I am using the following code:

```
 library(ggplot2)
 mtcars$carb <- as.factor(mtcars$carb)
 mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)
 sort_table <- data.frame("carb" = c(1,2,3,4,6,8), "class" = c("class A", "class B", "class A", "class C", "class B", "class A"))
 ggplot(mtcars) + 
      geom_boxplot(aes(x = carb, y = mpg, fill = am), 
          position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

This results in this plot:
[image]

How can I sort the boxplot at a higher level, i.e., by class, as defined in the sort_table data.frame? And how can I add labels that indicate each class? The desired result looks like this:

[image]

Please note that I need to apply this to a larger dataset, so I need to sort using the sort_table data.frame and **not** by "manual" ordering using something like `c(1,3,8,2,6,4)`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `merge` `mtcars` and `sort_table` first and then use `facet_grid`

```
ggplot(merge(mtcars, sort_table, by = "carb")) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = carb, y = mpg, fill = am), 
               position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(class), scales = "free_x", switch = "x", space = "free")
```

[image]

Add `+ theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "pt"))` if you want to remove the margins around the facets.

Comment: Very elegant solution! Thank you so much!